# Fastest method for "Part split"

Tags: modeling

I' am looking for a method to make this kind of part split on one object, without to have to separate the object in many parts, and then having to model all these split part.
[image]

Ideally in 3d with maybe 2 or 3 modifier to stack up or by doing a crease on a edge and doing an offset of that crease. Otherwise, in just visual with a texture to follow an edge.

The Goal is to be able to modified quickly the part without to worry about these detail in a design process.

Thank you